# How to limit repositories of an organization by pushedAt date?

Tags: github, github-api, graphql

Here is a GitHub GraphQL query:

```
query Foo($login:String!) {
  repositoryOwner(login: $login){
    repositories(first: 3){
      totalCount,
      nodes{
        name
        pushedAt
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way to modify this query so that results that come back are already filtered (limited) by `pushedAt` date? `pushedAt` exists on the node, and I can fetch it, but I would like to get only the subset of the organization's repositories that were `pushedAt` at a certain date. I hope to be able to limit the results by `pushedAt` date, and not sort it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
{
  search(first: 3, type: REPOSITORY, query: "user:MyOrg pushed:>2017-04-01T06:00:00Z") {
    edges {
      node {
        ... on Repository{
          name
          pushedAt
        }
      }
    }
    repositoryCount
  }
}
```